# Salesforce - Can I have a lookup field on two different object types?

Tags: salesforce

My client requested to have a field that can be a lookup on either contacts or users.

I know that Salesforce does something like this in some standard objects. For instance, the Task objects has fields "who" (lookup on account or contact) and "what" (lookup on case, opportunity, and more stuff). Also, I know the Owner field on Case can reference either a User or a Queue.

Can I make custom fields that look up on more than one kind of object?

Answer (score 3):

You can't create a custom lookup field that references multiple types. You would have to create 2 different fields.